# Django templates - Formatting strings

Tags: django, django-templates

I've these variables:

```
#Int
user.id

#Float (e.g. X.YYYY)
profile.rating
```

I need these formatted like so (the `` ` `` is delimiter):

```
<a href="/user/`user.id`/">`profile.rating`</a>
```

I've tried numerous ways to format them, but none worked. For example, concatenating them: `"<a href=\"/user/"|add:user.id|add:"\">"|add:profile.rating|add:"</a>"` gave me nothing (literally, *nothing*).

I suspect that this is because `add:` is numbers-first, but converting the numbers into string with either `slugify` or `stringformat:""` gave me, again, *nothing*.

**How do I do this?**

*Do note: I need to do this with filters since the result will be passed as a parameter to an include.*

**Update:**
Basically, I'm building a sort of modular include. It include looks like this:

```
<section>
...

  {% if custom_section %}
  <section id="{{ custom_section_id }}">
    {{ custom_section }}
  </section>
  {% endif %}

...
</section>
```

which means that I can't just directly include the values in a parameter, I need the markup that will go inside the nested `section`.

Comment: What kind of output you want? Why doesn't something like `"/user/{{user.id}}/"` work for you?

Comment: But isn't that impossible when "including" the values as parameters to an include? I.e. `{% include "XX" with stuff="/user/{{ user.id }}/" %}`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this _passed as a parameter to an include_ - do you mean the `{% include %}` tag?

Comment: The _include_-tag, yes. As in `{% include with param="" %}`, where `param` is a parameter.

Comment: To whoever down-voted: It would be nice if you could at least tell me *why* you down-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue with this piece of markup:

```
{% with "<a href="\"/user/" as link_start %}
  {% with profile.rating|stringformat:".1f" as rating %}
    {% with user.id|slugify as id %}
      {% with link_start|add:id|add:"/\">" as link %}
        {% with link|add:rating|add:"/5</a>" as data %}
          {% include "XX" with custom_data:data|safe %}

 {% endwith %} a couple of times
```

Key here is the `|stringformat:".1f"` and the `user.id|slugify` since without them, djangos [worthless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_acronyms:_I#IMO) templating language defaults on the belief all values are numerical, and thus crap comes out.

Of note is the `|safe` as well, as without it the language escapes the value.

Answer (score 0):

> Do note: I need to do this with filters since the result will be
>   passed as a parameter to an include.

You can pass them directly to include, as it will take context correctly.

```
{% include user.id %}
```